# ASP.NET/MVC Multiple View Models (Product Page & Reviews)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Product VIEW, I am wanting to include the corresponding product reviews on the same page that is presented to the user.

```
<!---A SINGLE PRODUCT--->
<div class="product">
...
</div>
<!--MANY REVIEWS-->

<div class="reviews">
...
</div>
```

In order to retreive the VIEWS, the ProductID is needed. How would pass both the ProductModel and ReviewModel to the ProductPage View?

Comment: u may need to use partial view

Comment: What does your controller code for the products and the reviews look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one model per view.  What you can do is use the ViewBag to make any additional information available to the view.

A better way would be to create a new view model, ProductDetailsViewModel which holds all the data you need, populate it in the controller and pass it to the view.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm I mis understanding the question?  The OP asks "How would pass both the ProductModel and ReviewModel to the ProductPage View?".  Which you cannot do.